# Built-in function (or terse method) to convert from DateObject to Python datetime in Python?

Tags: date-and-time, python, wolfram-client

When using the [Wolfram Client Library for Python](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/) in a Python program there appears to be no built-in function to convert a [`DateObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html) in to a Python `datetime` object.

```
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl, wlexpr

wolfSession = WolframLanguageSession()
```

With `date_values` as `DateObject`s in Python

```
dt = wl.DateObject([2019,1,1,0,15]);
date_values=wolfSession.evaluate(
    wl.DateRange(
        dt,
        wl.DatePlus(dt, [1*15, 'Minute']),
        wl.Quantity(15, 'Minute')
    )
);

print(date_values)
```

> ```
> [DateObject[[2019, 1, 1, 0, 15], 'Minute', 'Gregorian', -3.0], DateObject[[2019, 1, 1, 0, 30], 'Minute', 'Gregorian', -3.0]]
> ```

The only way I have found to convert these is by parsing the `"ISODateTime"` string from [`DateString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateString.html) in Python.

```
import iso8601

p_dates=list(map(
    lambda d: iso8601.parse_date(d), 
    wolfSession.evaluate(
        wl.Map(
            wl.Function(wl.DateString(wl.Slot(1),'ISODateTime')),
            date_values
        )
    )
));

print(p_dates)
```

> ```
> [datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 15, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 0, 30, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)]
> ```

```
wolfSession.terminate()
```

This seems verbose considering many types automatically convert between a Wolfram session and Python (and vice versa).

Am I missing a built-in function to do this?  If not, is there a terse method of converting a list of Wolfram `DateObject`s into Python `datetime` objects in Python?

Comment: You should look in the WolframClientLibrary code, esp. [here](https://github.com/WolframResearch/WolframClientForPython/blob/e6ffc3b3a9ad9d0da09a081df138157987b884fd/wolframclient/deserializers/wxf/wxfconsumer.py#L16). The library appears to provide a way to automatically convert types over by registering a consumer object. By knowing the structure of a Mathematica `DateObject` you can directly construct the `datetime` one. I know this isn't terse, but it *is* extensible and really the way things like this ought to be done in general.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Interesting. I think I will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

I just happen to deal with such cases recently and have done some preliminary work, which is hoped to be helpful.

Please see the code below:

1. `TimeSeries` consumer:

```python
# TimeSeries in wl
class TimeSeriesConsumer(WXFConsumer):
    """Implement a consumer that maps TemporalData to pandas.series with DatetimeIndex."""

    # represent the symbol TemporalData as a Python class
    TemporalData = wl.TemporalData

    def build_function(self, head, args, **kwargs):
        import datetime
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        if (
            head == self.TemporalData
            and len(args) == 4
            and args[0].name == "TimeSeries"
        ):
            ar_data = np.array(args[1][0])[0]
            dt = args[1][1][0]
            start, end = [
                datetime.datetime.strptime(
                    "-".join([str(x) for x in x_dt]), "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.%f"
                )
                for x_dt in dt[:2]
            ]
            freq = pd.to_timedelta(*dt[-1])
            idx_dt = pd.date_range(start, end, freq=freq)
            ser_dt = pd.Series(ar_data, index=idx_dt)
            return ser_dt
        # otherwise delegate to the super method (default case).
        else:
            return super().build_function(head, args, **kwargs)
```

2. `DateObject` consumer:

```python
# DateObject in wl
class DateObjectConsumer(WXFConsumer):
    """Implement a consumer that maps TemporalData to pandas.series with DatetimeIndex."""

    # represent the symbol DateObject as a Python class
    DateObject = wl.DateObject

    def build_function(self, head, args, **kwargs):
        import datetime

        if head == self.DateObject:

            list_dt = [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
            for i, x in enumerate(args[0]):
                list_dt[i] = x
            str_dt = "-".join([str(x) for x in list_dt])
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(str_dt, "%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S.%f")

            # when timezone is available
            if len(args) == 4:
                utc = args[-1]
                delta_dt = pd.to_timedelta(utc, unit="h").to_pytimedelta()
                dt = dt.astimezone(tz=datetime.timezone(delta_dt))
            return dt
        # otherwise delegate to the super method (default case).
        else:
            return super().build_function(head, args, **kwargs)
```

For example, to convert a `TimeSeries` into a `pandas.Series`, one can use the above as follows:

```python
ser_sim = binary_deserialize(
        wl_session.evaluate_wxf(exp_wl), consumer=TimeSeriesConsumer()
    )
```

where `exp_wl` is the wl `TimeSeries` object.

Comment: Great answer (+1)